# How can I revert libavcodec-extra-54 to libavcodec54?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, libav

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.3 32bit platform.
I want to compile opencv, it requires libavcodec-dev. I want to install it but it needs a long list of packages. It would be easy if I could just install them all with just one click. Unfortunately I encounter conflicts of packages now. Because  I installed libavcodec-extra-54 in the past and it's not compatible with libavcodec54 which is one of the packages libavcodec-dev needs. I attempted to remove libavcodec-extra-54 naively, but it listed dozens of applications to be removed.

IIRC I encountered the same problem while switching from libavcodec54 to libavcodec-extra-54 but I don't remember how I managed to install libavcodec-extra-54 in the past.

I need that know-how to revert it now but I don't remember now.
I hope anybody knows how to manage what I encounter.

Comment: It lists "to be removed" packages in synaptic, I tried to remove it from terminal, it only reports package conflicts.  http://paste.ubuntu.com/13259181/

Comment: "to be removed" packages in synaptic are such as acidrip, aegisub,  ardesia, audacious,  blender, browse-plugin-vlc ....

Comment: It gives another dependency error. http://paste.ubuntu.com/13259238/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31549/discussion-between-a-b-and-kenn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the package `libavcodec-extra-54`

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-all libavcodec-extra-54
```

Download and install `libavcodec54`

```
apt-get download libavcodec54
sudo dpkg -i libavcodec54_*.deb
```

---

To be sure, run

```
apt-cache policy libavcodec54 libavcodec-extra-54
```

you should now see something like this

```
libavcodec54:
  Installed: 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Candidate: 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     6:9.11-2ubuntu2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages
libavcodec-extra-54:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Version table:
     7:1.2.6-1~trusty1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
     6:9.11-2ubuntu2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages
```

Comment: Unfortunately apt-get install -f gives dependency errors :(

Comment: I was late checking the result